# process.env.npm_package_version undefined when running inside docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, docker, npm

I am trying to print the current package.json version inside my node.js app.
When I run it locally it works fine using `process.env.npm_package_version`.

However when I build it using a Dockerfile and then deploying it to a container the `process.env.npm_package_version` variable is undefined. Does anyone know what is going on?

My dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.13.2
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --only=production
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Part of my package.json:

```
"name": "node-discord-bot",
"version": "2.2.4",
"description": "",
"main": "./build/server.js",
"scripts": {
  "start": "node .",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "build": "tsc"
},
```

Comment: if the process you followed when running in your host is same as running in docker container it should work, can you see if any differences are there in those steps...!

Comment: I was running npm 7 and the docker container was running npm 8. Seems like something is broken in npm 8 because when I update my dev machine it also stops working.

Comment: there you go, so maybe use a different node base image which is compatible to your code, or maybe try to change npm versions in one of the docker steps, before running commands